Annihilators & Laplace transform
Let the following differential equation :
$ \begin{align*}
\left[\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}+\frac1{\tau}\right]V_{_\text{OUT}}&=\frac{A\sin\left(\omega \,t\right)}{\tau}\tag{1}\label{eq1}
\end{align*} $
Transformed into this equation using annihilators : $ \begin{align*}
\left[\left(\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\right)^2+\omega^2\right]\left[\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}+\frac1{\tau}\right]V_{_\text{OUT}}&=\left[\left(\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\right)^2+\omega^2\right]\frac{A\sin\left(\omega \,t\right)}{\tau}
\\\\
\left[\left(\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\right)^2+\omega^2\right]\left[\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}+\frac1{\tau}\right]V_{_\text{OUT}}&=0
\end{align*}$
I want to know how we would get this general expression after transforming the last equation into the s-domain:
$ \begin{align*}
v_{out}&=A_0\exp\left(\frac{-1}{\tau}t\right)+A_1\cos\left(\omega\,t\right)+A_2\sin\left(\omega\,t\right)
\end{align*} $
Here is what i did, by expanding the expression , and applying the laplace transform on both sides:
$\begin{align*}
\frac{d^3}{dt^3}V_o + \frac{d^2 V_o}{\tau \cdot dt^2}  + \frac{\omega^2 \cdot dV_o}{dt}  + \frac{\omega^2 \cdot V_o}{\tau} = 0
\end{align*}
$
$ \begin{align*} 
s^3 V_o(s) + \frac{1}{\tau} s^2 V_o(s) + s \omega^2 V_o(s) +\frac{\omega ^2}{\tau} V_o(s) = 0 \end{align*}$

The approach is the same as any Laplace transform problem. First, expand the differential equation out into individual terms, then apply the transform on each term (best done using a Laplace transform table), solve the resulting algebraic expression for $\mathcal{L}{V_{OUT}}(s)$, and then convert back to $V_{OUT}(t)$ using inverse Laplace transform.

On a side note, the values of $A_1$, $A_2$ and $A_3$ can be solved in terms of $A$ and $\tau$, by substituting the general solution back into the original equation and equating coefficients. These "additional" constants arise from a kind of
"loss of information" that occurs when using the annihilators this way.

@Tom , hey sorry for the late response, can you check again what i did? thanks

The operator expression doesn't contain factor $\omega$.
Use $\omega^2$ instead.

you are so right @gpmath better now?

@KnowledgeSeeker Are you aware that your last equation has the solution $V_o(s)=0$ ?

Yes thats the problem im facing, so how did they get the general solution though? @gpmath

You should get $V_o(s)= \frac{A \omega +\tau v_0 \left(s^2+\omega^2\right)}{(s \tau +1) \left(s^2+\omega^2\right)}$ if you transform eq. $(1)$ directly.

what is $ v_o$ ? @gpmath

$v_o$ at $t=0$: $v_o(0)$

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
